# What is the best way to analyze data captured from sar?

Tags: linux, performance, sar, statistics

I've got some sysstat data that has been captured from servers with SAR, and I'm unsure what is the best way to analyze that data.

I've found ksar, but it seems to be quite old and out of date. I'd prefer to be able to analyze in a graphical manner, but I can't seem to find any other useful tools for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of graphical analysis is usually done with tools that are designed to do so.  I use `munin`, but there are several other tools that do similar tasks. They gather the data into a data store from which graphs can be readily generated.  However, there are tools that can extract the data into formats that can be graphed.

I would use `awk`, `perl`, or `python` to extract the data to be graphed in tabular format starting with a timestamp.  This data can then be converted to graphical format.  `gnuplot` is one tool that can be used to do the conversion either interactively or to image files.

EDIT: As noted, there are a variety of tools that will report data reported by SAR.  Some will store historical data and allow graphing of historical data.  For a quick analysis of current status I use `top`.  However, when I need to review recent past performance i use the storee `sar` data. The text format allows me to isolate the critical data quickly by slicing, dicing and comparing statistics.

Comment: So essentially, the answer is that there is not a ready-made tool that can take data gathered using SAR, and analyze it without intermediate processing by the user.  That's what I had suspected, so thanks for that.